# how to add button dynamically in gridview column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have this code of gridview. how do i enable button to be add inside all column in each row other than first column using this code ? i dont have templatefield or others assign for gridview because i declare gridview display through this code. how can i achieve that ? this is my code :

```
`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //where request_date >= DATEADD(day,-8, GETDATE())
    con.Open();
    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.request_date,a.prod_line,a.jo_no,a.qty,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.need_by_date ,101) as need_by_date,b.process_id FROM CutPanelCard a LEFT JOIN CutPanelConfirmation b on b.req_id=a.req_id where request_date >= DATEADD(day,-8, GETDATE()) order by request_date", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dtTemp);

    ViewState["Information"] = dtTemp;

    try
    {


        {
            //DataTable dtTemp = (DataTable)ViewState["Information"];
            DataTable dtDistinctRecords = dtTemp.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "prod_line");
            DataTable dtStudentName = dtTemp.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "request_date");
            DataTable a = new DataTable();


            DataTable dtStudent = new DataTable();

            dtStudent.Columns.Add("request_date");
            foreach (DataRow rows in dtDistinctRecords.Rows)
            {
                dtStudent.Columns.Add(rows["prod_line"].ToString());
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dtStudentName.Rows)
            {

                DataRow dr = dtStudent.NewRow();
                dr["request_date"] = row["request_date"];
                DataView dv = new DataView(dtTemp);
                dv.RowFilter = "request_date='" + row["request_date"] + "'";
                DataTable dtStudentdtl = dv.ToTable();

                for (int i = 0; i < dtStudentdtl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                        string colValue = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["jo_no"].ToString();
                        string colValue2 = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["qty"].ToString();
                        string colValue3 = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["need_by_date"].ToString();
                        string colValue4 = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["process_id"].ToString();

                        dr[dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["prod_line"].ToString()] = "JO: " + colValue + "  Quantity: " + colValue2 + "  Need by Date: " + colValue3 + "  Completion Status: " + colValue4;


                }
                dtStudent.Rows.InsertAt(dr, dtStudent.Rows.Count);

            }


            GridView1.DataSource = dtStudent;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView_Row_Merger(GridView1);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Why not use `TemplateFields`. Then you'll be done in 5 minutes.

Comment: because i retrieve column gridview not same structure as column in database. i retrieve row in database from one column become each column in gridview.

Comment: Well, you're gonna have to if you want controls in each cell and keep the text also. If you add controls to autogenerated cell you'll lose the contents.

Comment: oh ok thank you @VDWWD :)